# wpf ViewModel Property Binding from another viewmodel

Tags: wpf, properties, binding, viewmodel

how do i bind a property declared in a viewmodel to take value from another viewModel?

let me explain

i have 2 ViewModels (Implements INotifyPropertyChanged) and 1 View

InvoiceView ( just my invoice design no matter if is a user control or window or a dataTemplate)

InvoiceViewModel

NoteListingVM (this viewmodel has a property let's name it TableRefID)

In the ViewInvoice i have an expander with it's dataContext set to (NoteListingVM) to show some notes that are linked with the specific invoiceID

I have a problem when i try the following

```
 <Expander Header="NOTES"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource AlternateForeGround}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel.DataContext>
                            <WendBooks:NoteListingVM TableRefID="{Binding InvoiceID}" x:Name="TransactionNotes"></WendBooks:NoteListingVM>
                        </DockPanel.DataContext>
```

A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'TableRefID' property of type 'NoteListingVM'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

so as the error said, i cannot use a property.

Then i think to use a DependencyProperty. But DependencyProperty cannot work properly in ViewModels if you implement an InotifyPropertyChanged. ( and this is what most users suggest when you implement a ViewModel - "INotifyPropertychanged")

DependencyPropertys are work well when you have a userControl or CustomControl. But this is not my case(i dont have a usercontrol or customControl i only have a ViewModel that i want to assign / pass "parameter" to the NoteListingViewModel when the InvoiceID changed)

so how i will send the InvoiceID (only xaml) to the NoteListingViewModel to filter and show only notes that are link to the current invoice i have front on me? what is the proper way? i am sure something i missed or misunderstand the mvvm pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Do it in a viewmodel-centric way instead: Make the `NoteListingVM` a property of the parent viewmodel.

Instead of structuring your application as a tree of views which own viewmodels that struggle to know what they need to about each other, make it a tree of viewmodels that own their own relationships. Festoon them with views that don't need to know about anything but their own viewmodels.

Note that the `InvoiceID` property below updates `Notes.InvoiceID` when it changes. Easy as pie.

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Notes = new NoteListingVM();
}

private int _invoiceID = 0;
public int InvoiceID
{
    get { return _invoiceID; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _invoiceID)
        {
            _invoiceID = value;
            Notes.InvoiceID = this.InvoiceID;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private NoteListingVM _notes = null;
public NoteListingVM Notes
{
    get { return _notes; }
    protected set
    {
        if (value != _notes)
        {
            _notes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML. You could wrap a `DockPanel` around the `ContentControl` if you want.

```
<Expander 
    Header="NOTES"  
    DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource AlternateForeGround}"
    >
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Notes}" />
</Expander>
```

## Alternate

You could also write a `NotesView` `UserControl` that has an `InvoiceID` dependency property, and bind that in the XAML. It would use the same `NoteListingVM`; you'd assign that via the `DataContext` property just as you've been doing. The user control's `InvoiceID` dependency property would have a change handler that updates the viewmodel's `InvoiceID`, which would let you use a binding to set the `InvoiceID`. That's a "proper XAML" way to do what you originally had in mind.

You could also entirely rewrite `NoteListingVM` as a `UserControl`, but that's more work and I don't see a whole lot of point to it.

You don't mix viewmodel/`INotifyPropertyChanged` properties with dependency properties in the same class.

Comment: aha:) i guess you are right , but is this the proper way to follow  when you have such requirement ? shouldn't be more convenient and acceptable path if you keep your central View Model separate from the other ViewModels? (either if they have some logic between of them or not ) just thinking.. ( thought that this what MVVM pattern is and dose.) somehow...

Comment: @user2160275 Who told you that? What problem are you trying to avoid by hiding your viewmodels from each other?

Comment: yes i think.. is this wrong?(correct me) , ( when we say hiding them i mean that why the InvoiceVM need to know that i have the NotesVM ? ) 
simply i have a view with 2 ViewModels and i expect to  share values between of them without ViewModels know each other ..

Comment: @user2160275 I just did correct you. If you don't want to listen, that's your choice. Good luck.