# MVVM Binding between two user controls with separate view models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

i have a window which loads a Customer table and another user control of input fields, when i select i wish to populate the user control inputs. I currently have a datagrid that a selected item is set in the CustomerViewModel through binding. When this is selected it updates a textbox with the selected items property such as name, email, etc. I have a CustomerSettingsViewModel which contains multiple input fields. I am trying to bind the selected item to inputs within this model, however as the CustomerViewModel doesn't know about the CustomerSettingsViewModel i cant see the binds within the textbox inputs.

The views are loaded using `DataTemplate` using the datatype.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type VM:CustomerVM}">
                <View:Customers/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:CustomerSettingsVM}">
                <View:CustomerSettings />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:SuppliersVM}">
                <View:Suppliers/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:SuppliersSettingsVM}">
                <View:SupplierSettings/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedMain}"  Margin="0,135,0,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedSettings}"  Margin="105,53,10,45"/>
```

These are set and get the correct views depending on the datatype that being presented.

**MainVM.cs**

```
Customer = new CustomerVM();
CustomerSettings = new CustomerSettingsVM();
SelectedMain = Customer;
SelectedSettings = CustomerSettings;
```

within the `CustomerVM` i have a get and selected with binds to anything within the customer view, however how can i get the customer settings view to see the selected customer has changed and populate the inputs?

**CustomerVM.cs**

```
 public Customer SelectedCustomer
        {
            get { return _selectedCustomer; }
            set
            {
                _selectedCustomer = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedCustomer");
            }
        }
```

i have upload a simple solution of my problem onto [GitHub](https://github.com/bish25/MVVM_user_control_binding) Might give a better understanding of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Where *is* the customer settings view? What's its DataContext?

Comment: i have declared the datacontext in the view with `<UserControl.DataContext>` and the datacontext is `CustomerSettingsVM`

Comment: Oh, OK. Don't do that. Don't use `UserControl.DataContext`. `CustomerSettingsVM` needs to be a member of the parent VM. If you can't or won't tell me where you're putting the customer settings view in the XAML, I can't provide any further help. But I can tell you that you have *two copies* of `CustomerSettingsVM`, and the one in the UI isn't the one your main viewmodel knows about.

Comment: @edPlunkett i have update the question i am using content controls. The `CustomerVM` contains a Customer object in which i want to be used in the `CustomerSettingsVM`.

Comment: Thanks! Now, what does this mean? * i can get the selected customer name to view within that view, however not in the input view.*? Can you describe what you see on the screen that's wrong, and what you expected to see instead?

Comment: i hope that makes it clearer, sorry still very much new to MVVM and implementation.

Comment: MVVM is not easy, so don't apologize for not being new. But please describe SPECIFICALLY what things you WANT to see on the screen of your computer, the glowing rectangular screen on your computer where you are reading this comment. Please also describe SPECIFICALLY what things you ACTUALLY see instead. No vague abstractions, no hopes and dreams. *"i can get the slected customer to bind the Customers.xaml"* means nothing in English.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i have created a simple version of my solution onto GitHub as i am struggling to explain it, see question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed a few concepts about MVVM, maybe you should go back to [basics](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html).
Basically, your viewmodels have to be a "testable copy" of your view.
So if your target is to build a Customer View containing Customer Settings, what you need is:

- a CustomerViewModel with a CustomerSettingsViewModel property
- a CustomerView using CustomerViewModel as datacontext
- a CustomerSettingsView declared into your CustomerView binded to the CustomerSettingsViewModel from the CustomerViewModel

Another way to put this: if you want a view to contain another view, you can have a viewModel to contain another viewModel.

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354292/wpf-viewmodel-property-binding-from-another-viewmodel) could show you how to use a vm as a property of another vm.

Please see [my proposed solution using your GitHub example](https://github.com/Ouarzy/MVVM_user_control_binding). Basically your problem is that you should not use directly the Customer Model in a View, but create a CustomerVm instead, and just delete the CustomerSettingVm.
You might understand better my implementation by reading how I'm used to deal with [MVVM](http://www.ouarzy.com/2016/04/14/clarifying-mvvm-with-ddd/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I most probably have missed a few concepts about MVVM as still learning, thanks for the link thats what i have based my project on. So from my understanding i should have the CustomerSettingsViewModel declared within the CustomerViewModel which will have access to the SelectedCustomer? Sorry still trying to get my head around it all.

Comment: See edit question. if you want to provide an example git repo, I might try to show you the code.

Comment: i have upload a simple solution of my problem onto [GitHub](https://github.com/bish25/MVVM_user_control_binding) Might give a better understanding of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Ok, my undertanding is that you have a table Customer display into the CustomerVM (which may be renamed CustomersVm), and a bunch of input fields in CustomerSettingsVm. And when you select a line in the Customers Grid, you would like to populate the CustomerSettings view. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, if you have look and ran the GitHub project you will see it binds to the text box. i can get it working when i change the `ContentPresenter` to `<View:Customer/>` and `<View:CustomerSettings/>`. Then rename the `<VM:MainVM/>` within the MainWindow to `<VM:CustomerVM/>`. however i have a navigation that when click will load a different table and settings, for example suppliers.

Comment: Maybe its my navigation and how i load the views as i am using content presenters and `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the update and reading through the code its starting to make sense, reading your blog also gave me a better understanding. Just one question can i not apply a content presenter instead of `<View:CustomerSettings DataContext="{Binding SelectedMain}"  Margin="563,53,10,45"/>` as this will change as well. so if i selected suppliers this will load suppliers and suppliersSettings. I do really appreciate your help as well as its been difficult getting my head around it.

Comment: thanks i managed to work it out, but i have looked at your repo and its different. can you view my repo and see how i did it and if this approach is good? Again thanks for being patient with me :)

Comment: To understand why my implementation is better, you'll need to explore Unit Testing (http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/mvvm-and-unit-testing/). The fact that you create a view (CustomerSettings) in your code behind does not respect the MVVM spirit, and makes the MainViewModel really hard to Unit Test.

Comment: Just an update, i have got my head around your approach and understand MVVM a little bit more. Also i have read through your blogs which helped. However i stupidly migrated my account to my old account which has a Ask question ban from when i first started programming as i had to change emails, could you help a fellow programmer out and just look through some of my questions to see how i could improve as been updating my questions with no effect. thanks again :)